# Is there an easy way to get different types data from API calls in a single program?

Tags: python, rest, api

If I want to get data from API that has different GET like "/names", "/schools", "/subjects", and more is there an easier way to find out how many GETs there are in the API or an easier way to get them all?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard for how to get all the names from a REST API.

Comment: Not unless the API author has made all of the endpoints available as its own endpoint. Perhaps you could scrape the documentation page?

Comment: Be careful with the terminology, I don’t think the use of GET like this makes much sense.